# If minutes are doubles, why is the minimum of minutes 0?

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to take the minimum of minute values.

```
> typeof(minutes(7))
[1] "double"
> min(c(minutes(7),minutes(8)))
[1] 0 
> seconds(min(as.numeric(c(minutes(7),minutes(8)))))
[1] "420S"
```

Why is that?
After all it works with regular doubles:

```
> typeof(c(7.0,8.0))
[1] "double"
> min(c(7.0,8.0))
[1] 7
```

Comment: `7` is a number. `minutes(7)` is a `Period`, as can be shown with `dput(minutes(7))`. (I'm assuming you are using `lubridate`, since otherwise you need to specify where you're getting `minutes`, etc.)

Comment: Use `str()`, not `typeof()`:  it's much more informative.

Comment: Probably a shorter way exists, but you might try: `min(c(dminutes(7),dminutes(8))) * dseconds(1) / dminutes(1)`.  The first term alone will tell you the max in seconds (420), but the last part will convert to minutes. Could also use `/60` if you want to do the conversion yourself.